# Variance of a Certain Random Matrix

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Let $A$ be a random $n \times n$ matrix, whose entries $X_{ij}$ are independent and $P(X_{ij}=1)=P(X_{ij}=-1)=1/2$. Compute $\text{Var}(\text{det}(A))$.

I'm not really sure how to even proceed here. I think the question may imply that each $X_{ij}$ is either $1$ or $-1$ almost surely. So perhaps that helps things out.

I would really appreciate any help with this question.

Comment: It seems to me that if you *think* that the question *may* imply this, this is rather an advanced problem and perhaps you should solve some more elementary problems first. (No disrespect intended; it's just that it's demotivating and unhelpful to work on problems that are too hard for your current level.) (The question does imply this.)

Comment: I walked away from the problem for a bit and realized that is what the problem implies. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of the determinant:
$$\det(A)=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\varepsilon(\sigma)X_{1,\sigma(1)}\cdots X_{n,\sigma(n)}$$

The random variables $Y_\sigma=\varepsilon(\sigma)X_{1,\sigma(1)}\cdots X_{n,\sigma(n)}$ are not independent, but we have:

$$V(\det(A))=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}V(Y_{\sigma})+\sum_{\sigma\neq\sigma'}Cov(Y_\sigma,Y_{\sigma'})$$

Now we can show that

1. $V(Y_\sigma)=1$ for any $\sigma\in S_n$
2. $Cov(Y_\sigma,Y_{\sigma'})=0$ for $\sigma\neq\sigma'$

This will prove that $$V(\det(A))=n!$$

First, $V(Y_\sigma)=V(X_{1,\sigma(1)}\cdots X_{n,\sigma(n)})$ since $|\varepsilon(\sigma)|=1$. I'll still denote this by $Y_{\sigma}$.

By independance of the $X_{ij}$, we get that
$$V(X_{1,\sigma(1)}\cdots X_{n,\sigma(n)})=\prod_{i=1}^nE(X_{i,\sigma(i)}^2)-\left(\prod_{i=1}^nE(X_{i,\sigma(i)})\right)^2$$

$E(X_{i,\sigma(i)}^2)=1$ since $X_{i,\sigma(i)}^2=1$ a.s., and $E(X_{i,\sigma(i)})=0$. So $V(Y_\sigma)=1$.

Now $Cov(Y_\sigma,Y_{\sigma'})=E(Y_\sigma Y_{\sigma'})-E(Y_\sigma)E(Y_{\sigma'})$.

By independence, $E(Y_\sigma)=E(Y_{\sigma'})=0$. Then

$$E(Y_\sigma Y_{\sigma'})=E\left(X_{1,\sigma(1)}\cdots X_{n,\sigma(n)}X_{1,\sigma'(1)}\cdots X_{n,\sigma'(n)}\right)$$

As $\sigma\neq\sigma'$, there exists $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $\sigma(i)\neq\sigma'(i)$. Then $X_{i,\sigma(i)}$ is independent from all the other variables in the product so you can factor its expected value which is $0$. We just proved that $Cov(Y_\sigma,Y_{\sigma'})=0$.

Comment: Thanks, this is a well thought out solution. I appreciate the help!